# find the radius of convergence of $(1+(-1)^{n}2^{1+n})x^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I ran into this question and I don't really know how to find the radius of convergence.

the power series is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1+(-1)^{n}2^{1+n})x^{n}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%281%2B%28%E2%88%921%29%5En+2%5E%281%2Bn%29%29x%5En+from+n%3D0+to+infinity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$(1+(-1)^n2^{1+n})x^n=x^n+2(-2x)^n$$

Using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence), $\sum_{0\le n<\infty} x^n$ is convergent iff $|x|<1\iff -1<x<1$ and

$\sum_{0\le n<\infty} (-2x)^n$ is convergent iff $|-2x|<1\iff -\frac12< x<\frac12$

So, we need to fulfill both condition

Comment: @user76508, my pleasure

Comment: This is rather interesting but I'm not sure it is true, or perhaps I'm misunderstanding something: you seem to have conditioned the original series' convergence to the convergence of those two series in which you can separate the original one. Of course, one direction is obvious (if both separated series converge then their sum also does), yet the other direction is, I think, false. You get though the correct answer...Would you mind addressing my doubt? Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio, as the multiplier is $2>0,$ the given series will only  converge if the two summand series converges. Had the multiplier been negative, we could not say so as  $\infty-\infty$ can be  finite. Please let me know your idea

Comment: The multiplier is positive only when $\,n\,$ is even, but even then: you seem to imply that $\,\sum(a_n+b_n)z^n\,$ converges iff $\,\sum a_nz^n\;,\;\;\sum b_nz^n\;$ converge each separatedly. This is what I meant I'm not sure it is true.

Comment: @DonAntonio, why don't we think the two series $\sum x^n, \sum (-2x)^n$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$1/R=\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}$$ for a series $\sum_{n\in \mathbb N}a_nz^n.$

In our case $a_n =(1+(-1)^{n}2^{1+n})$, so

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}=\limsup_{n\to\infty} |1+(-1)^{n}2^{1+n} |^{1/n} $$
$$=2\limsup_{n\to\infty} |2^{-n}+2(-1)^{n} |^{1/n}=2,$$ hence your radius of convergence is $R=\frac 12$.

Comment: how to i go further from here?

Comment: @user76508 see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$1+(-1)^n2^{1+n}=\begin{cases}1+2^{n+1}&,\;\;\;n\;\text{even}\\{}\\1-2^{n+1}&,\;\;\;n\;\;\text{odd}\end{cases}$$

and we then have

$$\left|\;1\pm2^{n+1}\;\right|\le2^{n+2}\implies2\le\sqrt[n]{\left|\;1\pm2^{n+1}\;\right|}\le2\sqrt[n]4\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\;\ldots\ldots$$